# Android Room onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE not working

Tags: android, android-room

I am using the room database in my android application.

While inserting data into user I have added:

```
 // Not working onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE/REPLACE
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
        void insertUser(User users);
```

But it is not working. I also tried onConflictStrategy.REPLACE but it is still not working.

User class (Getter and Setter are there):

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_name")
    @NonNull
    private String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public User(@NonNull String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, user.name) &&
                Objects.equals(email, user.email);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(name, email);
    }
}
```

I have also looked at other questions and tried their solution but still facing the problems.

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? What are your specific symptoms?

Comment: @CommonsWare onConflictStrategy.REPLACE and onConflictStrategy.IGNORE not working. It is still inserted the duplicate records

Comment: AFAIK, `OnConflictStrategy` is simply using `INSERT OR ` (e.g., `INSERT OR REPLACE`), and so [it only affects `UNIQUE`, `NOT NULL`, `CHECK`, and `PRIMARY KEY` constraints](https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html). Do the duplicates that you insert have the same primary key as do existing records? Or are you expecting the conflicts to take into account your name and email fields?

Comment: @CommonsWare This is the first time inserting. I am expecting the conflicts on name and email fields. Can we achieve this?

Comment: You would need to add unique indexes to those columns.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add unique indexes:

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = {"user_name", "email"}, unique = true)})
public class User {
...
}
```